# User Data Handling between two plugins

Tags: plugin-development, user-access

I have a facebook authentication plugin installed. I also have a premium content plugin installed.

When a user authenticates with facebook they are logged in as a subscriber.

When a user signs up for premium content a unique user account is generated, separate from the facebook user account created already.

Is there a way to make both plugins share the same information for users? When a user signs up for premium content can they just use the facebook account, or if they are a user with no account just use the facebook authentication.

For clarification the reason I am trying to use facebook authentication is because 1:) it is easy for the user, and 2:) my hope is people are not willing to pass on there username and password to others if it is also their facebook login.

Comment: Please link both plugins. Hard to say anything if we can't see the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is less likely to be done already - those are totally 2 different random plugins.

You might have to do your own coding

I'd go with database trigger, once something is inserted in one plugin table or the other, same data inserted in the other.

You might have to validate that usernames are unique in both table, something not easy to do code wise - so i guess you just add some standard string to the target table in the trigger